# How to register Apache Storm supervisors to Apache Zookeeper

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I'm following http://jayatiatblogs.blogspot.com/2011/11/storm-installation.html & http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup to set up Apache Storm cluster in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS at AWS EC2.

My master node is 10.0.0.185. My slave nodes are 10.0.0.83, 10.0.0.124 & 10.0.0.84 with myid of 1, 2 and 3 in their zookeeper-data respectively. I set up an ensemble of Apache Zookeeper consists of all the 3 slave nodes.

Below are my zoo.cfg for my master node & slave nodes:

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5

dataDir=/home/ubuntu/zookeeper-data
clientPort=2181

server.1=10.0.0.83:2888:3888
server.2=10.0.0.124:2888:3888
server.3=10.0.0.84:2888:3888

autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
```

Below are my storm.yaml for slave nodes:

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
 storm.zookeeper.server:
     - "10.0.0.83"
     - "10.0.0.124"
     - "10.0.0.84"
#     - "localhost"
 storm.zookeeper.port: 2181

# nimbus.host: "localhost"
 nimbus.host: "10.0.0.185"

 storm.local.dir: "/home/ubuntu/storm/data"
 java.library.path: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"

 supervisor.slots.ports:
     - 6700
     - 6701
     - 6702
     - 6703

# worker.childopts: "-Xmx768m"
# nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx512m"
# supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx256m"
```

The storm.yaml file in master node is similar to slave nodes, except the supervisor.slots.ports is commented with #.

Below are the /etc/hosts file in both the master node & slave nodes:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.0.185 ip-10-0-0-185.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal stormNimbus
10.0.0.124 ip-10-0-0-124.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal slaveRain
10.0.0.83 ip-10-0-0-83.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal slaveCloud
10.0.0.84 ip-10-0-0-84.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal slaveLightning
```

when I issue command ***echo status | nc 10.0.0.124 2181*** on slave node 10.0.0.124:

```
Zookeeper version: 3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
Clients:
 /10.0.0.124:53790[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)
```

I start up zookeeper & supervisor in all the 3 slave nodes. The another 2 slave nodes didn't register to the zookeeper, although I set up the zookeeper in a cluster mode.

When I issue storm rebalance in the Topology Summary of Storm UI, instead of allowing new slave node to be added and run concurrently with old slave node, the new slave node replace old slave node to run the topology.

Each time only a single slave node is running the topology.

What is the possible issues & how should I solve it?

Comment: Just a minor point, Storm and Zookeeper don't use the master/slave terminology. So I'm a little unsure what you mean when you use that terminology. Do you mean nimbus/supervisor when you talk about master/slave nodes?

Comment: I have no experience with AWS. But if not all supervisors do register, this issue should not be related to the cluster setup of ZK. Furhtermore, what do the supervisor logs show? There should be an error message if a supervisor cannot connect.

Comment: Yes, I mean nimbus & supervisor when I mean master & slaves.

Comment: solve the problem already. Please refer to comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525661/how-to-configure-multi-node-apache-storm-cluster/33561298?noredirect=1#comment55914464_33561298